# How do I correctly Override in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

In my superclass, I have the following method:

```
public int getSpeed(String t)
{
    return 0;
}
```

In my subclass I them overide the method with this:

```
public int getSpeed(String t)
{
    return x;
}
```

I then have the following:

```
ArrayList<super> //contains only objects of the subclass
for (super s:collection)
{
    s.getSpeed("");
}
```

And this always returns 0. How do I get it to return x?

---

EDIT: My code was written almost exactly as Bala R's solution shows, however I just did something stupid to my X that caused it to round to 0 every time. His solution therefore is correct.

Comment: Why does `getSpeed()` take a String?

Comment: @BlueRaja, I pass in the name of the subclass of the other class that calls it. And before you say it, I already know its extremely badly written that way but I know of no better. Its supposed to be different types of vehicles on different types of roads.

Comment: Sounds like you should either use generics, or have a third class which handles what to do with different vehicle/road-type pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your `x` in the subclass is actually zero or not initialized ?

I just tried ( [Ideone link](http://ideone.com/aPdcW) )

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        new Main();
    }

    Main(){
        ArrayList<Super> list = new ArrayList<Super>();
        list.add(new Sub());
        list.add(new Sub());
        list.add(new Sub());
        for (Super s:list)
        {
            System.out.println(s.getSpeed(""));
        }
    }
}

class Super {
    public int getSpeed(String t) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    @Override
    public int getSpeed(String t) {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

and the output is

```
1
1
1
```

Comment: I have it declared at the top of the class.

`public class Sub extends Super
{
    private int x= 70;`

Comment: @NeoNMD see this http://ideone.com/g6GMl . I changed it to return x and initialize it to 70.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is as you have written it in the question, then you've implemented overriding correctly.  Alternative explanations for seeing zero `speed` values include:

- The value of `x` has not been initialized, or has been set to zero.
- The comment `//contains only objects of the subclass` is incorrect.

But I don't think we can say anything more without seeing the REAL code ...

---

Adding an @Override annotation to the overriding method is good way to ensure that you've overridden something ... and is good practice ... but it won't make any difference here.